# velocity template engine 1.7 line break issue

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I have a velocity template that generates a Java class and, it's gobbled with new line breaks and this doesn't happen always.

My template looks like this,

```
#foreach( $str in $elm.mylist )
#if($selected == $str.how)
#if($str.how == "value")
    //some comment
#end
#if($str.how == "value")
    //some comment
#end
#if($str.how == "value")
#if($foreach.index == 0 || $foreach.index == 1)
    @CustomAnnotation(value = "$!str.value")
#else
    //@CustomAnnotation(value = "$!str.value")
#end
#else
    @CustomAnnotation(value = "$!str.value")
#end
#end
#end
```

generated java file looks like this,

```
//some comment
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "sample value
")
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "no value found")
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "change this")
@CustomAnnotation(value = "no value found")
public MyClass varibleName;

//some comment
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "sample value
")
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "no value found")
//@CustomAnnotation(value = "change this")
@CustomAnnotation(value = "no value found")
public MyClass varibleName_1;
```

how to avoid this new line break?

Answer (score 1):

The line breaks after `sample value` are most certainly contained in the `$str.value` string. So you can do something like:

```
$!str.value.trim()
```

to remove them.

By the way, if you wan to get rid of line breaks introduced by Velocity directives, you can end the line with `##`:

```
#if($str.how == "value")##
```